# Can someone please move this question to this site?

Tags: discussion, support

I have asked [this](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/5978/how-do-icelandic-people-mention-an-entire-family) question on the Language Learning website. It has not yet received an answer. But a user told me in a comment that Travel site is more suitable for my question.

I asked there for a move because I lacked the required reputation to do so, but no one did a thing regarding it. So I want to ask someone here to move it for me.

Comment: You have to ask people there (the moderators actually) to close it with a request where to move it. But I fear that it also does not fit well on Travel, (but if they move it I am happy to let the community decide.) Some questions just do not fit Stack Exchange. You can also close the question there and ask a new one here. (But remember we are a travel site, not a cultures site.)